# How to pass variable from shell to Ansible playbooks

Tags: shell, ansible

I have a `deploy.sh` script that I call to trigger deploy tasks with ansible. In a simplified form, this is a deploy command triggered by `deploy.sh`

`DEPLOY_CMD="ansible-playbook -i hosts/$1 deploy.yml --extra-vars="site=$2 theme=$3""`

This is a fragment of a task:

```
project_pre_build_commands_local:
   - path: "{{ project.local_path }}/web/app/themes/{{ theme }}"
     cmd: npm install
   - path: "{{ project.local_path }}/web/app/themes/{{ theme }}"
     cmd: bower install
   - path: "{{ project.local_path }}/web/app/themes/{{ theme }}"
     cmd: gulp --production
```

Unfortunately the shell errors out with:

> msg: cannot change to directory
>   '/home/ltarasiewicz/dev/bedrock-stack/bedrock-ansible/{#
>   project.local_path #}/web/app/themes/{# theme #}': path does
>   not exist

The `theme` variable I'm passing to the `deploy.sh` is 'cpkg'. The specified directory exists. More so, If I define the path like:
`- path: "{{ project.local_path }}/web/app/themes/cpkg"`(get rid of `{{ theme }}` variable), all goes well - the process completes without errors.

I'm really confused. Would appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 3):

You have a problem with quotes in your `DEPLOY_CMD`.

When you `echo $DEPLOY_CMD` in your `deploy.sh` script you should see something like this:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts/ deploy.yml --extra-vars=site=
```

The variable does not contain your parameters.

To solve the problem you can use single quotes instead:

```
DEPLOY_CMD="ansible-playbook -i hosts/$1 deploy.yml --extra-vars='site=$2 theme=$3'"
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing that it was something with DEPLOY_CMD. However, when I echo it in my `deploy.sh`, and when I pass variables to it, only `site` variable is present, and not theme. Unfortunately single quotes are not parsed well by Ansible. It errors out with "Exception: error while splitting arguments, either an unbalanced jinja2 block or quotes
". There must be another way to pass several extra vars to Asnible

Comment: I can't confirm that. Just tested this: `ansible-playbook -i inventory/test test.yml --extra-vars='site=B theme=A'`. Both vars `site` and `theme` are available in my test playbook.

Comment: Now I might know where the problem lies. I've been running `deploy.yml` thourgh `deploy.sh`, but I was looking for `theme` in a different file. Obviosuly `extra vars` do not become global, accessible by all files.